# Best practice for displaying multiple views in a single page

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am working on a Drupal 7 website where there are many pages which utilize multiple views.

The way I am doing this right now is by creating a page from Drupal admin panel, and in the edit mode of that page I am calling views_embed_view to display those multiple views.

[image]

Other ways I could do this is by creating a template for that page, and putting my code inside the template.

Yet another way is to use View Fields View (https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and embed the second view inside the first one.

**I want to know, performance wise which is the best practice?**

Comment: your job (call views by `views_embed_view` has better performance that `Panel` module. because panel module add more query in call,), bye default drupal cache views even in calling by `views_embed_view` . good job

Comment: is my way better than putting the same thing in a page.tpl.php file @zhilevan ?

Comment: I think another way is create a php block and call them in it with your php code, it use block caching,if you put in page.tpl.php maybe it has a little more performance(fewer query )  but if you want to follow MVC structure of drupal  use views and views in views .

Comment: You should not use php code filter, it's it's a wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) to display multiple views on a single page:

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.

Panels includes a pluggable caching mechanism, so it could be a good and easy option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) is a really good way to go, it will allow you to create pages and add them views or fields of entities if you use the context tool that comes with the module.

A couple of other things that might become handy are [EVA](https://drupal.org/project/eva) module that allows you to attach a view to an entity render page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use header and footer section of the view to show other views.

Step 1 : Create a view which is your own output to show.

[image]

Step 2 : Select add footer in your view and select "Global : View area" option to insert other view which you to show on that page.

[image]

Step 3 : Now you can select any view which you want to show on that page.

[image]